# Rails retrieving associated information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model-associations

I fail to find the correct syntax to retrieve associated information. I have a model 'companyaccount' that belongs to a model 'company'.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many :companyaccounts
end

class Companyaccount < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

In the View, I can easily retrieve both the 'Companyaccount' 'number' and the 'id' of the associated company through the 'company_id' field of the 'companyaccount' table.

```
<%= @companyaccount.each do |companyaccount| %>
 <%= companyaccount.company_id %>
 <%= companyaccount.number %>
<% end %>
```

The View is called from this basic Controller

```
def index
  @companyaccount = Companyaccount.all
end
```

Now, I do not want to have the company_id but the actual name of the company (housed in the 'company' table). I manage to do it for one specific company using a controller like this

```
def index
  @companyaccount = Companyaccount.all
  @company = Company.first
end
```

and then in the view change

```
<%= companyaccount.company_id %>
```

by

```
<%= company.name %>
```

but of course, this will retrieve, for each companyaccount, the same first company and not each of the company associated with the companyaccount. Could anyone provide me with the appropriate syntax to retrieve the associated company's name for each companyaccount in the "each" loop of my View? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want with this loop:

```
<%= @companyaccount.each do |companyaccount| %>
  <%= companyaccount.company.name %>
  <%= companyaccount.number %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate for this.

```
class Companyaccount < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :company
  delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true
end
```

and then you can call `<%= companyaccount.company_name %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  @companyaccount = Companyaccount.all
end
```

and in view

```
<% @companyaccount.each do |companyaccount| %>
 <%= companyaccount.company.name %>
<% end %>
```

for less db call you can change controller like

```
@companyaccount = Companyaccount.includes(:company).all
```